# Header is overflowing after I changed computer

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and this is the styling of my header:

```css
    header{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 5.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(17, 51, 122);
    align-items: center;
    }
```

Everything was fine, until I had to travel and couldn't take my PC with me, I could only take my laptop. Once I dowloaded everything (I keep my website files on github) and started working the website, I noticed that my header now overflows to the right, even though the width is set to 100%. Nothinng else is overflowing, just the header, any ideas on what it could be? My laptop does have a smaller resolution, but if that was the case, I imagine the whole website would be overflowing, instead of having everything adjust to screen size except for the header.

Comment: Would you test adding ` flex-wrap: wrap;` for me please ? I wanna check something :)

Comment: Is the browser zoom 100%?  Try `Ctrl+0`

Comment: If there is something that is inside the header that has a fixed size that could result in pushing the whole thing off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the css above is causing the header to overflow. For testing you could try making it `width:100vw;`. If that doesn't work, you should post a little more code.

Maybe the body or another parent of your header is overflowing, then the header overflows too.

Comment: I solved the problem by reducing the padding between the stuff I have in my Header. I guess I'm gonna have to make it responsive and reduce that padding on slightly smaller screens, since my laptop resolution is 1280x800 while my PC is 1920x1080

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to solve the problem by reducing the padding between everything in my header, and now I gotta make it responsive to a smaller screen bot not small enough to be a phone screen